# cakephp tag plugin: How to display the top X weighted tags using the cloud helper

Tags: cakephp, tags, cloud

I'm trying to use the [cakephp tag plugin](http://cakedc.com/downloads/view/cakephp_tags_plugin) to generate a tag cloud. If I follow the basic usage instructions it always retrieves the first X tag records instead of the top X tag records by weight. How can I get the top tags instead of the first tags?

Also I can't figure out what the weight field in the tags table is for, since it is always set to 0. The Tag cloud function though is still able to get size based on weight though.

there is an issue on it in the [issue tracker](http://cakedc.lighthouseapp.com/projects/59622/tickets/14-sorting-the-tag-cloud-by-top-or-random-occurrence#ticket-14-1)

Answer (score 0):

The tag helper was recently updated to record the occurrence of a tag and - if added by the user of the plugin - to record the occurrence for each model. Just add a field _occurrence to the tags table.

The weight is a normalized value based on the tag with the highest and lowest occurrence value. The weight field was dropped from the db schema, in fact it should have never been there.

https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/commit/ae31369ef54df9ebd55da47a5111b4ed54c4e158

Just order your find() by occurrence now and you might get what you want if i got you right.